# opencv imread exit code 0xC0000409

Tags: opencv, jpeg

The code is:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>

int main (int argc, char** argv) {
    auto path = "C:/Users/huhua/Pictures/11.jpg";
    auto img = cv::imread(path);
    if (img.empty()) {
        std::cout << "is empty" << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }
    cv::imshow("demo", img);
    cv::waitKey(0);
    return 0;
}
```

The 11.jpg exist. And if I use another 11.bmp. It works well.

After debug. The error is throw at libjpeg-trubo/src/jdatasr.c

```
fill_input_buffer(j_decompress_ptr cinfo)
{
  my_src_ptr src = (my_src_ptr)cinfo->src;
  size_t nbytes;

  // error is throw at here
  nbytes = JFREAD(src->infile, src->buffer, INPUT_BUF_SIZE);
  // ...
}
```

Is my libjpeg issue??

How to fix this?

The 11.jpg image:

[image]

Update:

[The OpenCV info](https://gist.github.com/huhuang03/e3f073595a38737f3fce3607cac2210e)

Update on 2021/10/19:

The reason is I set the `cmake_toolchain_path` after `project(xxx)`. I should set the cmake_toolchain_path before `project`.

https://github.com/microsoft/vcpkg/discussions/20802

Comment: Does imread works for other jpgs?

Comment: is this reproducible when using `auto path = cv::samples::findFile("lena.jpg");`? -- I tried loading the picture you added to the question. it loaded fine. this site might have altered the picture after upload, so that's not saying much.

Comment: what exact version of OpenCV do you use? use `cout << cv::getBuildInformation();` and add to your question (edit)

Comment: I donwload the image above, and use the `auto path = cv::samples::findFile("lena.jpg");` to load it, and the error still same. It's most likely the libjpeg issue.